# Make object as an array return error "Method must have return type"

Tags: c#, arrays, object, types, return

I follow the book Head First but I can't figure out why my object array cannot be declared. System keeps saying that 'method must have return type'. I know I can label each single object diffrent name like dog1, dog2, dog3 and create object like the with a Guy class but I am just wonder what I've done wrong that it can't be array dog[0], dog[1] etc. Can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Guy Joe = new Guy() {Money = 50}; 
        Guy Bob = new Guy() {Money = 75};
        Guy Al = new Guy() {Money = 45};


        Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];
        dog[0] = new Greyhound();
    }
    public class Guy
    {
        public int Money;

    }
    class Greyhound
    {
        public int StartingPosition;
        public int RaceTrackLengh;
        public PictureBox MyPictureBox = null;
        public Random Randomizer;
        public int Location;

        public bool Run()
        {
            Location += Randomizer.Next(5);
            MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition + Location;
            if (Location >= RaceTrackLengh)
            {
                TakeStartingPosition();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        private void TakeStartingPosition()
        {
            Location = 0;
            MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting code in lines 19 - 25 to a method, something like: `void InitialiseMyObjects(){Guy Joe = new Guy() {Money = 50}; 
        Guy Bob = new Guy() {Money = 75};
        Guy Al = new Guy() {Money = 45};


        Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];
        dog[0] = new Greyhound();}`

Comment: It supposed to be gambling game for betting on dogs. It is amount which each player have for game, but for now I am struggling on 20% of this project to full understand what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare them inside constructor:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Guy Joe = new Guy() {Money = 50}; 
             Guy Bob = new Guy() {Money = 75};
             Guy Al = new Guy() {Money = 45};


             Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];
             dog[0] = new Greyhound();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line `dog[0] = new Greyhound();` is a *statement*, whereas `Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];` for example is a field declaration with initialization.

Statements must be in methods, but for what you want to do there is another approach using intializer lists:

```
Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4]
{
    new Greyhound(),
    new Greyhound(),
    new Greyhound(),
    new Greyhound()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just put code like that

```
Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];
dog[0] = new Greyhound();
```

In a class, it has to go in the constructor or in an other method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       Guy Joe = new Guy() {Money = 50}; 
      Guy Bob = new Guy() {Money = 75};
      Guy Al = new Guy() {Money = 45};


    Greyhound[] dog = new Greyhound[4];
    dog[0] = new Greyhound();

    }
  }
public class Guy
{
    public int Money;

}
class Greyhound
{
    public int StartingPosition;
    public int RaceTrackLengh;
    public PictureBox MyPictureBox = null;
    public Random Randomizer;
    public int Location;

    public bool Run()
    {
        Location += Randomizer.Next(5);
        MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition + Location;
        if (Location >= RaceTrackLengh)
        {
            TakeStartingPosition();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void TakeStartingPosition()
    {
        Location = 0;
        MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition;
    }
}
}
```